# Raspberry Pi3 connection I2C

Tags: i2c

I am looking to connect an external battery to my Raspberry and know its level of charge. 
For that, I have to use a SMBus connection, so I can use the I<sup>2</sup>C ports of my Raspberry. But I can not recover the battery data.

My battery is on `0x0b`

I know that the first byte is a write byte and that the code is `0x16`, the other two bytes are readbytes and the code to have the level of charge is `0x0d`.

Could someone help me?

My program:

```
import smbus
import time
bus = smbus.SMBus(1)

bus.write_byte(0x0b,1)
x=bus.read_word_data(0x0b,0x0d)
print x

x=65535
```

Why this result?

Comment: Does `i2cdetect -y 1` detect the device?

Comment: What device is this? Where's the datasheet?

Comment: it's an external battery

Comment: http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slua475/slua475.pdf it's SMBus doc

Comment: @MathieuSollier that doc is a general SMBus doc. Can you add the part number or the data sheet of the chip which has the I2C command list

Comment: http://sbs-forum.org/specs/sbdat110.pdf
ça vous va ? merci beaucoup en tous cas